# "An avid user of social media to discuss the case"

Tags: infinitives

*An avid user of social media to discuss the case, Zellner's use of the tweet could be viewed as a statement of fact that witnesses are coming forward.*

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/making-a-murderer-lawyer-new-witnesses-2016-9

Don't you think that there is the preposition "for" before "An avid user…" omitted? Without the preposition the sentence seems to me being weird. The clause would be for me meaningful being tranformed in this way: (a) For an avid user of social media who discusses the case, Zellner's use…, (b) An avid user of social media to discuss the case could view Zellner's use…

Comment: The "missing" preposition isn't ***for*** - it's ***as***. Zellner used social media to discuss the case. ***He*** was an ***avid user** [of social media to discuss...]* But strictly speaking your example is defective, since the "primary" statement following that clause doesn't actually have Zellner (the aforementioned "avid user") as its subject. Syntactically, it's got *his **use** [of the tweet]* as the subject - which isn't quite right, but it's a fairly common "mistake" that wouldn't normally be noticed in contexts like this.

Comment: ...fixable with, say, *[**As**] an avid user of social media..., **Zellner used** the tweet **in a way which** could be viewed as...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: +1 for a spot-on answer.  I would upvote it, if it were an answer instead of a comment....

Comment: It did not occur to me that "An avid user of social media" is related to Zellner. I thought that "An avid user" is somebody who reads the tweets of Zellner.